# Cordova - setTimeout with anonymous function firing immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, kendo-ui, leaflet

I'm using Cordova, Kendo ui, and leafletjs maps in an android app. What I want to do when I open a particular view is get a div to appear, wait three seconds, and then hide the div. This should be simple, but no matter the length of time I put in the timeout the div always appears and disappears immediately. I tried using Jquery show and hide at first, but then read that adding and removing classes is better with Phonegap.

js:

```
utils.hideLoading();        // calls kendo hideLoading function
$("#myDiv").removeClass( "opacityOff" );
$("#myDiv").addClass( "opacityOn" );
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#myDiv").removeClass( "opacityOn" );
    $("#myDiv").addClass( "opacityOff" );
}, 3000);
```

css:

```
#myDiv.opacityOff{
  display:none;
  opacity:0;
}

#myDiv.opacityOn{
  display:block;
  opacity:1;
}    

#myDiv{
  width: 11em;
  height: 11em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50% auto 0 auto;
  margin: 32vh auto 0 auto; 
  background-color:#000000;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

Why would setTimeout be executing this anonymous function immediately?

I'm thinking this has something to do with leaflet re renders, but I don't understand it well enough to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by just adding `z-index:999;` to my OpacityOn class. This was confusing for me because the div appeared for a second, and I thought that if z-index was the problem that it wouldn't appear at all. It looks like when leaflet maps redrew itself it gave itself a higher z-index. Don't fully understand why, if someone else with more knowledge of leaflet would like to clarify feel free.